# getElementByName does not seem to work

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, getelementbyid

I'm using Flex 4.6 and have a AIR application

I have a Panel with many labels on it.  I need to access these labels from another class.
I don't want to pass all the labels objects. so I thought about passing the panel container in then access the labels through the getElementByName() method.

Here is my mark up:

```
<s:VGroup includeIn="SLA_textView" width="100%" height="100%"
paddingBottom="10" paddingRight="10">
<s:Panel id="SlaTextViewPanel" width="100%" height="100%"
 title="test View">
   <s:Label id="lbTotalBooks" name="test" x="82" y="62" />
</s:Panel>
</s:VGroup>
```

the actionscript code look like this:

```
getLabels(Container:Panel){
  var _Container:Panel = Container;

//var tempLabel:Label =  _Container.getChildByName("test") as Label;

var n:int = _Container.numChildren;
  for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var c:DisplayObject = _Container.getChildAt(i); 
    trace(c.name);
}

var tempLabel:Label =  _Container.getChildByName("test") as Label;
```

Why is `tempLabel` always `null`?

So I tried to loop through the name of the object on the Panel and the test label don't even show up? so I have something wrong somewhere.

Trace:

```
instance1333
PanelSkin1074
```

Comment: You're not supposed to use methods like `getChild()` with Spark containers, because behind the scenes that Label is not a direct child of that Panel; you should use `getElement()` and the like. Also `name` is a relic from the Flash API. Why do you need this anyway? I can't think of any reason.

Comment: What I have is a web services from c# that returning a table. The return listener is in the class. So I need to wait for the event from the web service to finished before I can uses the data to populate the labels. I not sure if there is a better way or not? I'm looking into another way of managing this. I move the call to the class to keep the code simple. not sure if this all makes sense or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When and where do you call a `getLabels` method? It's possible that labels have been created but not initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
var element:Group = "searchId" in this ? this["searchId"] as Group : null;
```